# xcode codesign error - signature invalid

Tags: xcode, identity, keychain, codesign

I am trying to build my app to a release build so I can upload it to the store, but I can't get xcode to sign it properly. Currently, my build settings are as follows:

```
    Project settings:
    code signing identity - iPhone developer: My identity
    any ios - iPhone developer: My identity
```

The target settings are the same as project settings

I have used this identity to build to a device without any problems

I have two identity certificates in my keychain, both are valid, one is an iPhone developer identity, the other is an iPhone distribution identity. In the xcode organizer, both show up.

I am not able to select the distribution identity in my project or target settings. Adding the identity manually creates an error that the identity could not be found in any profile.

I have searched and read the entire internet by now, encountering many similar problems, however the provided solutions either do not work or give me new problems.

My guess is that I should build the app using the distribution identity to have it signed correctly.

Comment: When I build for release with the developer profile I get a warning: Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. When I try to use the distribution certificate I get an error: Code sign error: The identity 'Iphone Distribution: My identity' doesn't match any identity in any profile.

Comment: have you added your device to your provisioning ?